# I have a problem with this how can I write multiple characters inside an array in c please get me a solution

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int generaterandomno(int n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % n;
}
int greater(char char1, char char2)
{
    //For Rock, Paper, Scissors - Returns 1 if c1>c2 and 0 otherwise. If c1 == c2 it will return -1

    if (char1 == char2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    else if ((char1 == 'r') && (char2 == 's'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((char2 == 'r') && (char1 == 's'))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if ((char1 == 'p') && (char2 == 'r'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((char2 == 'p') && (char1 == 'r'))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if ((char1 == 's') && (char2 == 'p'))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((char2 == 's') && (char1 == 'p'))
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int playerscore = 0, compscore = 0, temp;
    char playerchar, compchar;
    char dict[] = {'r', 'p', 's'};

    printf("Welcome to The Rock, Paper, Scissors Game, I hope you will enjoy\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // Take Player 1's input
        printf("Player 1:\n");
        printf("Choose 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper and 3 for Scissors\n");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        getchar();
        playerchar = dict[temp - 1];
        printf("You chose %c\n\n", playerchar);

        // Generate computer's input
        printf("Computer's Turn:\n");
        printf("Choose 1 for Rock, 2 for Paper and 3 for Scissors\n");
        temp = generaterandomno(3) + 1;
        compchar = dict[temp - 1];
        printf("Computer chose %c\n\n", compchar);

        // Compare the scores
        if (greater(compchar, playerchar) == 1)
        {
            compscore += 1;
            printf("Computer got it!!!\n");
        }

        else if (greater(compchar, playerchar) == -1)
        {
            compscore += 1;
            playerscore += 1;
            printf("It's a Draw!!!\n");
        }

        else
        {
            playerscore += 1;
            printf("You got it!!!\n");
        }
        printf("You: %d\nComp: %d\n\n",playerscore, compscore);
    }

    if (playerscore > compscore)
    {
        printf("----------------------\n");
        printf("------You Won!!!------\n");
        printf("----------------------\n");
    }
    else if (compscore > playerscore)
    {
        printf("---------------------\n");
        printf("---Computer Won!!!---\n");
        printf("---------------------\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("----------------------\n");
        printf("----It's a Draw!!!----\n");
        printf("----------------------\n");
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

`char dict[] = {'r', 'p', 's'};`

I have a problem with this  how can I write multiple characters inside an array in c please get me a solution. I want to write rock paper and scissors replacing this please get a solution for me.....

Comment: To begin with, please con't copy-paste text as a filler. Instead write a description of the problem you have, telling us possible inputs, the expected output and the actual output. Please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Change `dict` from 1D array to 2D array, i.e., array of arrays.

Comment: @SouravGhosh How Can I do it pls tell me in brief

Comment: OT: call `srand(time(NULL))` only once at the start of the program.

Comment: Again, please don't use filler text, or copy-paste the same thing over and over which doesn't add anything.

Comment: Please search in google by "C String". Eventually you will figure it out yourself and it will be the best way of learning basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is about outputting 'rock' instead of 'r' when confirming the choice.

You could create a 2 dimensional array to hold the strings instead of a one dimensional array. For example...

```
char rps[][] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
```

This would allow you to get at both the initials for example...

```
rps[0][0] would be 'r'
```

or the whole string...

```
rps[0] is "rock"
```

The important thing to note is that a string is just a char array with a null terminator.

These links will help explain a bit more.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-strings

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/array-of-c-string